# C# moon APNS: iOS Device Did Not Receive Notification

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm a newbie in iOS development. Recently, I tried to use moon-APNS to send push notification to my device. I followed every step in *arashnorouzi.wordpress.com*. And when I run my program and read the log, notification was successfully sent to APNS server, but I never receive notification on my device. What is possibly wrong? Is there some setting I should do on my device or the iOS application? I only change the device token, certificate path, password at the example code. Here is my code:

```
        var payload1 = new NotificationPayload("b8bf91fcc66016a7bf96154f3c65c6c479385df98094394c2514682152c29968", "Message", 1, "default");
        payload1.AddCustom("RegionID", "IDQ10150");

        var p = new List<NotificationPayload> {payload1};

        var push = new PushNotification(false, "D:\\certificate\\aps_development.p12","aswin123");
        var rejected = push.SendToApple(p);
        foreach (var item in rejected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Anyone can help me? I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I changed the iPod Touch device I used for testing with another one and the push is working.

Answer (score 3):

Check did you done this:

enabled Push Notification of your app in the appID 
check , does you getting token while you run the application